# Apache NiFi adoption stats

Tags: apache-nifi

Before we put Apache NiFi to full use in our workplace, management asked to find how widely the product is used. Anyone know where I can get numbers like:

1. Active users.
2. How many downloads (including NiFi and sub projects)

Comment: You could compare trends over stackoverflow or Google https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=apache-nifi%2Ctalend

Comment: Thanks daggett. I also used the Docker image pull numbers: https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi. Then there are the GitHub repo stats. Anything else you suggest?